# Where does Meteor store atmosphere package templates/files

Tags: meteor, atmosphere.js

How can I modify source/templates of packages that I am using inside my Meteor Project.

For example, I download the package from Atmosphere, begin using the package and want to make some minor tweaks to the package.

What is the best approach to making changes to a installed Atmosphere package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *fork* the package from the github source and make changes to your own version. If you think those changes might benefit others then you can make a *pull request* for your changes and, if the original author(s) agree, your changes can now benefit others.

If you make changes in the deployed package under your project directory then those will probably be clobbered the next time you run `$ meteor update`

If you're still curious as to where they live, look under `/.meteor`